# UUID v5 creating different UUIDs for same input with same namespace

Tags: amazon-ecs, uuid, amazon-opensearch

Why are there duplicates in my opensearch index? To prevent duplicates, I am using UUID v5 with a namespace which I define in my config:

```json
// default.json
{
  //...,  
  "uuidConfig": {
    "namespace": "b23ecf16-9506-4b1a-810a-9ab7770ec409" // not my real namespace
  }
  //...
}
```

In my data there is a `name` and an `ownerId` field. If these fields are the same, I want the same UUID to be used. Here is the relevant code snippet:

```js
const { v5: uuidv5 } = require('uuid')
const NAMESPACE = require('default.json').uuidConfig.namespace

module.exports = (data) => {
  const baseUrl = 'https://my.baseurl.com'
  const foundEntity = duplicateCheck(data)
  const index = {
    _index: 'my-index-name'
  }

  // keep old data, overwrite old data with new data
  const res = {
    ...foundEntity,
    ...data
  }
  const thePayload = createPayload(data)

  // ... irrelevant code
  createIndex({
    url: `${baseUrl}${index._index}/_doc/${uuidv5(
      res.name + res.ownerId,
      NAMESPACE
    )}`,
    payload: thePayload,
  })
}
```

createIndex function:

```js
const createIndex = ({ url, payload, pathParams = 'filter_path=result,_version', config }) =>
    new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        inspect(`createIndex called with url: ${url}, params: ${pathParams} and payload: %o`)(
            payload
        )
        axios
            .put(`${url}?${pathParams}`, payload, {
                headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
                ...config,
            })
            .then((res) => {
                inspect('called create Index success: ')(true)
                resolve(res)
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                inspect('creating index responded with an error')(err)
                reject(err)
            })
    })
```

It works as expected in my integration system, but in QA it produces different UUIDs for the same inputs. One thing that came to my mind is that I am using 1 instance of the service in my integration system and multiple instances in QA. But from my understanding, as long as the function gets the exact same input *and* uses the exact same namespace, it should not matter. And the configuration is the same for all instances of this service in QA.

I am using AWS Elastic Container Services and AWS Opensearch.

Am I expecting the wrong thing or is there something wrong with my usage?

Edit:
as Requested here would be an input example (as stated and checked multiple times, the 2nd entry comes in with the exact same data [except for the `id` field] but gets a different uuid):

```json
{
  "id": "7388eb38-7d2a-4a13-ae0b-7cef3a96293d",
  "name": "Traumhotel Sörgenhof",
  "ownerId": "d1767ebd-0332-4454-92ef-29d543ab671e",
  "city": "Musterstadt"
}
```

Comment: It should produce the same uuid. This is almost impossible to help debug if you don't provide actual sample inputs. Chances are something unrelated is wrong.

Comment: uuid v5 is basically just an SHA1 of your input + namespace (and some bits set to fixed values). So if two calls to the generator produce different output, it's quite save to assume the inputs were different. Because there is literally no chance, that such an issue exists unnoticed in a library like `uuid` (which ranks in the top 25 of the most depended on packages). And it's impossible to help unless you can provide an example, when the exact same input leads to different outputs. Maybe an issue with character encodings? Or a misconfiguration in one of your QA instances?

Comment: is there a known issue with AWS ECS and this package with multiple instances? for example that the namespace is not taken in correctly? i have not found something in that regard but the input is like in the example given. its completly the same, no hidden characters or anything. the only difference between the 2 environments is, that one has multiple instances and the other does not

Comment: There is nothing special to AWS ECS in your code. Those instances work completely independently of each other. And they are just running a node process, which is just reading the `default.json`. Where do `res.name` and `res.ownerId` acutally come from? Are you 100% sure, all instances have the same `default.json`. The code you show is is fine, the chance that the `uuid` package has an error is near to non-existant. So the best guess is still a misconfiguration or differences in the data ...

Comment: When you say different outputs for the same inputs: Do they differ for *all*  inputs or just for some of them. Do you have multiple instances generating the same output, but only one generating a different one? Can you pin the differing output to a specific instance? Are all instances based on the very same base image, ie same version of os, node?

Comment: They are all running on the same version and have the same configuration. What i have not done yet is to have a look into the log streams of the *different* instances. I just looked at the general logs insights with combined logs. maybe you are right and its just one broken instance. the strange thing is, that sometimes it works just fine and other times it does not, which would hint at this problem. Thanks a lot